# Error with peek() function of a Stack class in c++

Tags: c++, templates, stack

I am trying to implement the peek() function of a Stack class and have this issue where I cannot return the top object of the stack, but instead get an error. I have tried removing the & to the peek function and tried to set it to a const, but I still get errors. Would the issue be outside of this function? as I am not sure what else I can try to solve this problem.

Error:

```
LStack.h:55:28: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ 
to 
an rvalue of type ‘int’
return data.get_current();
```

LStack.h

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> 

template <typename T>
class LStack
{
    public:
    //mutator member functions
    LStack(){}
    ~LStack(){}

    void push(const T& obj) //insert obj at the top of the stack
    {
        data.add_to_head(obj);
        numofstacks++;
    }

    T pop() //remove and return the top object from the stack, error if stack is empty
    {   
        if (is_empty()){
            std::cout << "Stack is empty";      
        }
        else{
        data.remove_from_head();
        numofstacks--;
        return data.get_current();  
        }
    }

    bool is_empty() const //return a boolean indicating whether the stack is empty
    {
        return (size() == 0);
    }

    //query member functions
    int size() const  //return the number of objects in the stack
    {
        return numofstacks; 
    }
    //return a reference to the object at the top of the stack, NULL if the stack is empty, (also refered to as top())
    T& peek() 
    {
        if (is_empty()){
            std::cout << "Stack is empty";  
        }
        else{
        //return top of the stack object
            return data.get_current();
        }
    }

    private:
    LinkedList<T> data;
    int used;
    int numofstacks;

};
```

LinkedList.h

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> 

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    public:     
        LinkedList() //constructor
        {
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
            list_length=0;
        }
        ~LinkedList()//destructor since we're creating the linked list on the heap
        {
            while (head != NULL)
            {
              remove_from_head();
            }
            tail = NULL;//not sure if in or out of while loop
        }

        LinkedList(T& item)
        {
            head = new Node<T>();
            head->set_data(item);
            tail = head;
            list_length = 1;
        }

        void add_to_head(T item)
        {
            if (list_length == 0){ //if list is empty
                head = new Node<T>();
                head->set_data(item);
                tail = head;
                list_length = 1;                
            }
            else //Else if list is not empty.. Insert node at the head
            {       
                Node<T>* head_insert = new Node<T>();
                head_insert->set_data(item);                
                head->set_prev(head_insert);
                head_insert->set_next(head);
                head = head_insert;
                list_length++;
                head_insert = NULL;
            }
        }

        void add_to_tail(T item)
        {           
            if (list_length == 0){
                head = new Node<T>();
                head->set_data(item);
                tail = head;
                list_length = 1;
            }
            else  //insert node at tail 
            {               
                Node<T>* tail_insert = new Node<T>();
                tail_insert->set_data(item);
                tail->set_next(tail_insert);
                tail_insert->set_prev(tail);
                tail = tail_insert;
                list_length++;
                tail_insert = NULL;             
            }
        }

        void remove_from_head()
        {
            if (list_length == 0){
                return;
            }
            else if (list_length == 1){

                delete head;
                head = NULL;
                tail = NULL;
                list_length--;
                return;
            }
            else
            {   
                Node<T>* temp_head = head;
                head = temp_head->get_next();
                delete temp_head;
                list_length--;
                temp_head = NULL;
            }
        }

        void remove_from_tail()
        {
            if (list_length == 0){
                return;
            }
            else if (list_length == 1)
            {
                delete head;
                head = NULL;
                tail = NULL;
                list_length--;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Node<T>* temp_tail = tail;
                tail = temp_tail->get_prev();
                delete temp_tail;
                list_length--;
                temp_tail = NULL;               
            }
        }   

        std::size_t size()
        {
            return list_length;
        }

        T get_current() // RESULTS IN SEG ERROR
        {
            return current->get_data();
        }           

        void forward()
        {
            current = current->get_next();
        }

        void back()
        {
            current = current->get_prev();
        }

        void move_to_head()
        {
            current = head;
        }

        void move_to_tail()
        {
            current = tail;
        }

        private: //private members
        Node<T>* head; //point to start of list
        Node<T>* tail; //point to end of list
        Node<T>* current; //optional - used to refer to a node in our list
        std::size_t list_length;
};
```

Would the issue be outside of this function? as I am not sure what else I can try to solve this problem.

Comment: If you promise that your function will return something (e.g. `T&`), then **you are obliged** to return that thing. You fail to do so when you call `peek()` and your `Stack` is empty. And C++ is not Java/Python, there are no `null` objects here. A pointer could point to nothing valueable (null), but null is basically an adress, not a special object type.

Comment: Saying that you get an error is not very helpful. Next time, describe the error. Provide the exact error text. Remember, all we know about your problem is what you tell us.